# Arduino SD -> File extension

Tags: c, embedded, arduino

I found this example to list all files on the SD Card:

void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
   while(true) {

```
 File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
 if (! entry) {
   // no more files
   //Serial.println("**nomorefiles**");
   break;
 }
 for (uint8_t i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
   Serial.print('\t');
 }
 if (entry.type
 Serial.print(entry.name());
 if (entry.isDirectory()) {
   Serial.println("/");
   printDirectory(entry, numTabs+1);
 } else {
   // files have sizes, directories do not
   Serial.print("\t\t");
   Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
 }
```

}
}

But I want to list only the files with an explicit extension and save them into an array. Any one of you an Idea? I can't found any Function to get the file extension by the SD Class.

Comment: By explicit extension, you mean files with an extension that you explicitly choose?

Comment: I mean, for eg. list all files with .jpg as extension and save them into an array

Comment: If there isn't a function to do that, you could discern the extension of a file by splitting `entry.name()` in the `else` clause by the `.`, given that file names usually follow the format `name.extension`, unless it doesn't have an extension, in which case it would be just `name`.

Comment: `if (entry.type` should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to loop through each of the filenames individually.

please look at an example of my code that does just this. Similar to the above comment by "A Person".

Here are links to my actual use [WHERE I use it](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_file_player_8ino_source.html#l00383) and [THE filter function](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_s_f_e_m_p3_shield_8cpp_source.html#l02024)

Note that my above use is using the SdFatLib, a more advanced version that SD (the IDE provided) library. Below I have adapted the same function for SD. Should work as it merely inspects the pointed char arrary's last 4 characters.

FYI - Note that the SD and SdFatLib only support 8.3 format.

```
void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
  while(true) {
    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }

    if ( isFnMusic(entry.name()) ) { // Here is the magic
      Serial.print(entry.name());
    }

    if (entry.isDirectory()) { // Dir's will print regardless, you may want to exclude these
      Serial.print(entry.name());
      Serial.println("/");
      printDirectory(entry, numTabs+1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
    }
    entry.close();
  }
}

bool isFnMusic(char* filename) {
  int8_t len = strlen(filename);
  bool result;
  if (  strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".mp3")
     || strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".aac")
     || strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".wma")
     || strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".wav")
     || strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".fla")
     || strstr(strlwr(filename + (len - 4)), ".mid")
     // and anything else you want
    ) {
    result = true;
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
}
```